# How much secure it is for admin to have login on android app to add or remove data on app?

Tags: android, security, data-security

I want to develop an android app for displaying and accessing some data. Is it safe for administrator to have login on the same user app so that he can add or remove data which will be stored on some server?

If not how should I do it?

Comment: Depends on the situation. Is the data accessed on the system as a file or from a server?

Comment: data is accessed from server

Comment: If the administration user/pass is also stored in the server, you could have it so when the user logs into administration, it checks the given user and pass on the server, then allows data to be accessed. That would be fine. If you store information about the administrative login locally (like in a file) then it's not secure

Comment: Okey. Thanks. Will be storing admin user/pass on server